# How to link a simple program in Windows with Mingw GCC

Tags: c, windows, gcc, linker, mingw

I have a simple "Hello World!" c program, named hello.c on my desktop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello world!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I run the following commands.

- I pre-process it with : *cpp hello.c > hello.i*
- I compile it with : *gcc -S hello.i*
- I assemble it with : *as -o hello.o hello.s*

All good so far. But, i'm unable to link it. I've tried, among other commands, these:

```
ld -o hello.exe hello.o
ld -o hello.exe hello.o -lgcc
ld -o hello.exe hello.o -nostdlib -lgcc
```

Nothing works. The link errors i get in every single case are :

```
hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x9): undefined reference to `__main'
hello.o:hello.c:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `puts'
```

How can i link this assembled program hello.o in order to finally produce the executable program hello.exe? What am i missing? [Using Windows 8.1, Mingw version 0.6.2.] Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `gcc -o hello.exe hello.c` do? "Nothing works" is not a very useful description of an error situation.

Comment: gcc is the compiler. That command will do all the work to produce the executable. I was going step-by-step. Now i'm in the final step and i want to link with the linker (ld).

Comment: Why are you linking? Is there an assembly file here? And what is your overall goal (To link the assembly and C Files ? ) ?

Comment: @amanuel2: What does assembly have to do with any of this? You need to link object code, irrespective of the source language that produced it. That could well be C.

Comment: @amanuel2 I have mentioned what i want to do. I want to link hello.o, to produce the executable. Isn't that what the linker is supposed to do (after accumulating all the libs). By the way why the negative votes?

Comment: @RestlessC0bra I'm going to say , I didn't downvote this question . Yeah , sorry i have been using linkers for combining C and Assembly files a lot lately , got confused :/ .

Comment: I think this has the answer you need. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164478/when-using-ld-to-link-undefined-reference-to-main

Comment: @LucasHarskamp Nope. No answer there works. It gives me the errors i provided above and more. Still trying to figure it out.

Comment: you could use `gcc` instead of `ld` to link, it will supply the appropriate libraries

Comment: So to link we must type gcc hello.o -o hello.exe. It does supply all the libraries automatically. It's probably impossible to type them all by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if your answers to clarification questions are not particularly useful:

Try something like

> ```
> ld hello.o -lmsvcrt -entry=_main -subsystem=console -o hello.exe
> ```

If you want to see the linker command line the standard gcc uses, invoke gcc like so:

> ```
> gcc test.c -o test -Wl,-v
> ```

The last lines output is what you should be using...

Comment: It *is* so complicated. If you'd use gcc, the compiler frontend, this would relieve you from that complications. Mingw is built to use the MSC runtimes. In my installation, libmsvcrt.a is in \MingW\lib - maybe you need to add a -L towards the dir where it is in yours.

Comment: See above edit in order to find out how the compiler frontend calls the linker.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compile something rather than experimenting with tools, don't link it using the linker directly. Use gcc, which will call the linker for you with the right options:

Compile step:

```
gcc -c hello.c
```

Link step:

```
gcc -o hello.exe hello.o
```

Or all in one:

```
gcc -o hello.exe hello.c
```

You can also use a simple Makefile, then run `make`:

```
all: hello.exe
```