# how solucion with mode linker in gcc

Tags: c, gcc, linker, kernel, ld

I'm doing a small kernel but at the time of making the link I get some help error with `ld`:

> ld -T linker.ld -o kernel boot.o main.o
>
> /cygdrive/c/Users/Loop/Desktop/nuos0.01-src-iso/src/main.c:4: undefined reference to `__main'
>   boot.o: In function`stublet':
>   src/boot.asm:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `main'

help me

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164478/when-using-ld-to-link-undefined-reference-to-main) may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When using ld to link, undefined reference to '\_\_main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164478/when-using-ld-to-link-undefined-reference-to-main)